# A high school quadratic problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, quadratics

"If $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n$ are distinct non-zero numbers such that

$$
\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {{a_k}^2}\right)x^2 +2\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k a_{k+1}\right)x + \left(\sum_{k=2}^{n} {{a_k}^2}\right)\le 0
$$"

We have to tell the kind of sequence that $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n$ produces. (Options are AP, GP, HP or AGP).

Since the coefficient of $x^2$ is positive and it says that the function is less than or equal to zero, that means the parabola is opening upwards (towards positive Y-axis) and it at least touches the X-axis. Thus I tried this: the discriminant $D \ge 0$ but things are getting quite messy.

Can anyone help me figure it out?

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @Vector do you mean *coefficient of $x^2?$* Can you explain why it is positive?

Comment: @user376343 edited... the coefficient is the sum of squares

Comment: @user376343 Also thanks for correcting my mistake. Yes its $x^2$.

Comment: How can the function be less than or equal to zero if the first term and last terms are always positive? Even if the sequence contains negative numbers, the middle term will not force the function to be less than zero all the time.

Comment: The given quadratic expression can be written as
$0\le \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (xa_k+a_{k+1})^2\le 0$

Then $xa_k+a_{k+1}=0 $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $(2\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k a_{k+1})^2-4\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}a_{k}^2\sum\limits_{k=2}^n a_{k}^2\leq 0$, so:
$(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}a_{k}^2)  x^2+(2\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k a_{k+1})x+ \sum\limits_{k=2}^n a_{k}^2 =0$ has only one solution. We can get $(2\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k a_{k+1})^2-4\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}a_{k}^2\sum\limits_{k=2}^n a_{k}^2=0$, then $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=c$, here $c$ is a constant.